# Android TextureView hardware acceleration with lockCanvas()

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, hardware-acceleration

I'm trying to use the hardware acceleration for Android with my canvas. I used to have a `SurfaceView` which I did `lockCanvas()` on to get a canvas which I later draw on, but I changed to `TextureView` since I couldn't get `SurfaceView` to use hardware acceleration. I'm currently trying to get this canvas to use hardware acceleration.

```
Canvas canvas = this.lockCanvas();
System.out.println(this.isHardwareAccelerated() + ", " + canvas.isHardwareAccelerated());
```

Gives me the output: true, false
(`this` is a `TextureView`)

Does anyone know why the `canvas` is not hardware accelerated, and how to make it so?

Edit: As far as I have found, it seems that I have to use OpenGL. However, I would still like to know if there are any announced plans to make hardware acceleration possible for such a canvas.

Comment: You should enable hardware acceleration for your activity: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#hwaccel .

Comment: You can check it in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html . I don't know if this is the answer. Because it says that check Canvas.isHardwareAccelerated can be used in Canvas.onDraw.

Answer (score 11):

`TextureView` works only when the application is hardware accelerated, but the `Canvas` it returns from `lockCanvas()` is currently never hardware accelerated. This means that you will draw inside the `TextureView`'s `Canvas` in software, but `TextureView` itself will be drawn using the GPU. Currently, the only way to get a hardware accelerated Canvas is to use the `onDraw(Canvas)` method of a View.

Answer (score 6):

Check the [Hardware Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) article.

Basically if you want your `TextureView` to be hardware accelerated you must make sure that hardware acceleration is enabled at some level in the context of your TextureView, i.e one of the following:

- At application level: 
  `<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>`
- At activity level:
  `<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />`
- At window level:

`getWindow().setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);`

Note that hardware acceleration is actually mandatory to use a [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html):

> TextureView can only be used in a hardware accelerated window. When rendered in software, TextureView will draw nothing.