# Android TextureView and hardware acceleration

Tags: android, hardware-acceleration

I am trying to implement the example shown on [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html). I have tried on three different devices running android 4 and above, and in all cases I get a black screen with this warning:

```
01-27 20:01:22.683: W/TextureView(4728): A TextureView or a subclass can only be used with hardware acceleration enabled.
```

I have turned on hardware acceleration in the application manifest:

```
<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    [etc...]
```

But the following check my custom view's onAttachedToWindow method always returns false

```
private class MyTextureView extends TextureView
{
    public MyTextureView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow()
    {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        Log.d("", Boolean.toString(mTextureView.isHardwareAccelerated()));          
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: do you have hardware acceleration enabled in your manifest?

Comment: You can enable or disable it in your manifest. Usually you do this on a per activity basis.

Comment: As mentioned in the original post, I have done so on the application level. According to the [hardware acceleration documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html), this is sufficient.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: According to the following resource the canvas in TextureView is not hardware accelerated (still true as of Android 6.0): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966228/android-textureview-hardware-acceleration-with-lockcanvas/14987164

Answer (score 0):

If you testing with Emulator then please check configuration for hardware acceleration.
Please check this thread for more info:
http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration