# Android Canvas and Hardware Acceleration?

Tags: android, ondraw, hardware-acceleration

Hi all I was wondering if it was possible to draw to an offscreen Canvas / Bitmap and take advantage of hardware acceleration or do I have to draw inside the `onDraw()` method of the `View`

For example I draw to an offscreen Bitmap by doing the following:

```
Bitmap.Config config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap buffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, config);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(buffer);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100, paint);
```

However `canvas.isHardwareAccelerated()` returns false and drawing is sluggish compared to:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100, paint);
}
```

where `canvas.isHardwareAccelerated()` returns true. Is there a way to draw to a Bitmap while taking advantage of hardware acceleration? Or do I have to draw directly to the screen in the onDraw method?

Thank you for your help :) I know in Java I can draw to a BufferedImage offscreen and it'll be hardware accelerated but maybe its not the same on a phone...

Answer (score 4):

Because in first case , you create the canvas, it is not backed up by a hardware layer.
Also, as of now, you cannot enable HWA on just any Canvas, it must belong to an HWA View.

A view on the other hand, has access to system's hardware capabilities. You can use that by calling `setLayerType( LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE)` as described in docs:

> Indicates that the view has a hardware layer. A hardware layer is
>   backed by a hardware specific texture (generally Frame Buffer Objects
>   or FBO on OpenGL hardware) and causes the view to be rendered using
>   Android's hardware rendering pipeline, but only if hardware
>   acceleration is turned on for the view hierarchy. When hardware
>   acceleration is turned off, hardware layers behave exactly as software
>   layers.

Also, The performance concern applies more to the rendering part, and less to drawing. All draw operations are recorded as a Picture object. Its the rendering operation where HWA plays an important role.

Comment: According to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9950775/935242
"Canvas returned by SurfaceView.lockCanvas() cannot be hardware accelerated at the moment."

Comment: The same for TextureView: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14987164/935242
"TextureView works only when the application is hardware accelerated, but the Canvas it returns from lockCanvas() is currently never hardware accelerated ... Currently, the only way to get a hardware accelerated Canvas is to use the onDraw(Canvas) method of a View."